# Set variable value 0 if select query returns NULL

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

I have the code below to get the sum of a column from a table.

```
 dim sumX as new oledbcommand
 sumX.commandtext = "Select sum(Xcolumn) from [Xtable] where id = "1234""
 sumX.commandtype = commandtype.text
 sumX.connection = con
 Dim z as oledbdatareader = sumX.executereader
 If z.read then
    y = z.getvalue(0)
 End if
```

The code above works. I want to know what if the code above does not get any value (null), how can I set the value of y to zero if the query's result is null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the query to this one:

```
Select IIf(sum(Xcolumn) Is Null,0,sum(Xcolumn)) from [Xtable] where id = "1234"
```

or this one:

```
Select Nz(sum(Xcolumn), 0) from [Xtable] where id = "1234"
```

There's an IIF function in access, it's better to set to 0 in the query.

See if this helps

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I just simplified your code to get more performance.It is very useful to use with aggregate functions like `Count()` or `Sum()` etc. When compare to `ExecuteReader()` , `ExecuteScalar()` uses fewer System resources

```
 Dim sumX As New OleDbCommand
 sumX.CommandText = "Select sum(Xcolumn) from [Xtable] where id = 1234"
 sumX.CommandType = CommandType.Text
 sumX.Connection = con
 y = IIf(IsDBNull(sumX.ExecuteScalar), 0, sumX.ExecuteScalar)
```

> ***ExecuteScalar()*** in SqlCommand Object is used for get a single value from Database after its execution. It executes SQL statements or
>   Stored Procedure and returned a scalar value on first column of first
>   row in the Result Set. If the Result Set contains more than one
>   columns or rows , it takes only the first column of first row, all
>   other values will ignore. If the Result Set is empty it will return a
>   Null reference.